# Symbian Development

Tags: c++, symbian

I am currently doing iphone development. I wish to do development in the Symbian platform too. Rather than Java i am familiar with CPP. Can you please help me by giving me some advice to get start in this development environment.? What all are the softwares i need to get installed in my system.? Expecting a positive reply.

Thanks and regards,

Shibin

Comment: Better now. read this: http://nerd5.com/tech-news/symbian-websites-to-close-on-december-17-2010.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things you will need:

- IDE. For Symbian C++ development there's the free, Eclipse-based [Carbide.c++](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Tools_Docs_and_Code/Tools/IDEs/Carbide.c++/).
- SDK. For example, the [S60 Platform SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Tools_Docs_and_Code/Tools/Platforms/S60_Platform_SDKs/) enables you to write applications for S60-based devices.

There's a lot of [getting started documentation on Forum Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Tools_Docs_and_Code/Documentation/Symbian_C++/Getting_Started.xhtml).

Comment: "For example, the S60 Platform SDK" - And I believe UIQ is now officially dead for future development. So unless there's a particular UIQ phone you want to write apps for (like if you have a Motorola or Sony-Ericsson handset) then S60 is more than just any example, it's the best example. In the medium term it might still be worth supporting UIQ if you want widest possible distribution, but I think start with S60, and in the long term S60 has "won".

Comment: Correct, UIQ is dead and gone.  However I'd be careful about saying S60 has one, since the recognisable bit of S60 - Avkon and its applications - is being replaced in the release after next with a Qt-based framework and UI.

Answer (score 7):

The [Qt framework](http://qt.nokia.com/) is a free cross platform C++ based environment, with Symbian support just around the corner (looks like its available in beta).  It supports desktop OSes (Windows/Mac) as well as device (Embedded Linux, Windows CE, etc.).  However as of this writing it does not support iPhone, RIM or Android.

Comment: Rumours abound that an iPhone version is in development although this would be a big surprise from a political POV (seeing as Nokia owns Qt.)

Comment: Upvote from me, because I wouldn't recommend anyone start developing native apps with anything other than Qt right now.  Qt libraries are going to go into Symbian^3 and are currently proposed to be the only application framework available in Symbian^4.  You can already use Qt on S60 3rd Edition FP1 and later devices.  There should be a smart installer for it available in the first quarter next year.

I'm sure Nokia would be very happy with Qt on iPhone.  The barrier has been Apple not accepting use of runtimes.  With the recent developments in the PhoneGap saga, looks like it might be OK.

Comment: P.S. "It supports all the major device platforms except for iPhone." Not true at all.  What about Android and Blackberry?

Comment: @Mark Wilcox - thanks for pointing that out, updated answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug: http://www.mosync.com

Even though the biggest benefit of MoSync is in the targeting of multiple platforms, it is a very nice C/C++ development environment for Symbian only! For a regular C/C++ programmer, everything should feel considerably less alien than using Symbian C++.

Answer (score 0):

Java/J2ME has much better tools and documentation, simpler libraries to use, and a bigger community. So unless you REALLY need to use C++ because of performance or specific API's you need, I suggest you use J2ME instead. I will probably be quicker to learn J2ME from scratch than to learn how to use the Symbian C++ libraries.

As stated by others, Qt might also be a viable option, but I haven't worked with it yet.

Answer (score -2):

The power and simplicity of Qt is further expanding its presence in the mobile world. The latest version of Qt will provide core support for **Symbian S60** development and a technology preview of support for Maemo 5.

```
                                                  ---quoted from forum.nokia.com
```